# Error Cannot read property 'beforeLoadComplete' of undefined JqxChart,

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jqwidget

I have a problem with jqxchart. I want to create chart in MVC 5 but i have a problem: ***Can not read property 'beforeLoadComplete' of undefined***
Code is as Follows.

```
@section scripts {
    <title id='Description'>test</title>

    <link href="~/OnlineRankingScripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/OnlineRankingScripts/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/OnlineRankingScripts/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>   
    <script src="~/OnlineRankingScripts/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script src="~/OnlineRankingScripts/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
    <script src="~/OnlineRankingScripts/jqwidgets/jqxchart.js"></script>
```

...............

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var source1 = {};
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    url: '/Home/GetOrders',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        source1 = data.d;// $.parseJSON(data.d);

                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                });

         // var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source1, { async: false, autoBind: true, loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { alert('Error loading'); } });
          var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source1,
  {
      autoBind: true,
      async: false,
      downloadComplete: function () { },
      loadComplete: function () { },
      loadError: function () { }
  });


        });
    </script>
    }
```

Comment: What is solution for this?

Comment: why is my place of employment using jqwidgets in ~2020 facepalm thats the real question here